# 'IntegerArray' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run a linear regression on a small dataframe I'm getting from an SQL query.

When running the example below (with a dummy dataset) everything is working fine:

```
# initialize list of lists
data = [['tom', 10, 20], ['nick', 15, 40], ['juli', 14, 70]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'value'])
  
# print dataframe.
df

X = df.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1, 1) # values converts it into a numpy array
Y = df.iloc[:, 2].values.reshape(-1, 1)

linear_regressor = LinearRegression()  # create object for the class
linear_regressor.fit(X, Y)  # perform linear regression
Y_pred = linear_regressor.predict(X)  # make predictions

plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.plot(X, Y_pred, color='red')
plt.show()
```

Now this is the data I'm working with:

```
          segment      ahid  pageviews_before_registration  visit_number_before_registration
0       long tail  45883641                             72                                21
1       long tail  49232488                             83                                15
2        unfunded  50757270                             46                                 6
3        unfunded  53214754                             30                                 9
4        unfunded  48812290                            248                                41
...           ...       ...                            ...                               ...
437456   unfunded  53253195                             25                                 5
437457  long tail  52374558                             25                                 6
437458   unfunded  53426345                             25                                 6
437459  long tail  50966914                             25                                 8
437460   unfunded  47672416                             25                                 6
```

This is the query I'm running to get it:

```
query = """
    ...some sql...
"""
query_job = client.query(
    query,
    location="US",
) 

df = query_job.to_dataframe()
print(df)
```

when running `X = df.iloc[:, 2].values.reshape(-1, 1)` I have the following error `AttributeError: 'IntegerArray' object has no attribute 'reshape'` Why is that? How is my dataframe different from the previous dummy dataframe I've shared

#edit1

```
print(df.dtypes)
[437461 rows x 4 columns]
segment                             object
ahid                                object
pageviews_before_registration        Int64
visit_number_before_registration     Int64
dtype: object
```

#edit2

when running `df.iloc[:, 2]`, `df.iloc[:, 3]` it seems that I have the correct values i.e. values from `pageviews_before_registration`  and `visit_number_before_registration` columns...

Comment: What are the dtypes of the dataframe? E.g. `print(df.dtypes)`

Comment: I ran your code with the head of the sample df contents and it works just fine, this suggest there's some odd values at some point. Check the validity of the `ahid` column

Comment: Did you try to check the result of, for example, `df.iloc[:, 2]`? Is it as you expect?

Comment: @NickODell added edit to my question. to Karl yes. also edited my question

Comment: Can you try something like `X = df.iloc[:, 2].astype('int64').values.reshape(-1, 1)` to force it to not use the nullable types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working when I'm casting the entire dataframe as an object `df = df.astype(object)`. If someone can explain why.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have *numeric-like columns* and change the indexes in [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) :

```
X = df.iloc[:, 2].values.reshape(-1, 1) # instead of `.iloc[:, 1]`
Y = df.iloc[:, 3].values.reshape(-1, 1) # instead of `.iloc[:, 2]`
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: why do you mean by numeric-like columns? I want to run the correlation on pageviews_before_registration  and column visit_number_before_registration and they are numeric columns

Comment: And have you tried changing the indexes of `.iloc` as I mentionned in the answer ?

Comment: in my question I'm saying I'm running `X = df.iloc[:, 2].values.reshape(-1, 1)` this is the same you are mentioning in your answer no?

Comment: That wasn't what you described at first. I can see that you made an edit to your question twice. Anyways, I can't reproduce the issue..

Comment: yes I added edit#1 and edit#2. Maybe my issue is around what you say numeric-like columns? What do you mean by that? I do have numeric like columns... no? pageviews_before_registration and visit_number_before_registration are Int64... they shouldn't be?

Comment: What I mean by *numeric-like*, columns that hold numbers that are cast to `object` but this seems not to be the case here..

Comment: I will try to make my issue reproductible using a public dataset from BigQuery

Comment: There are definitively something around `object`. Pls see my own answer and add your comment if you can... thanks!